# Subprograms and Arrays in Turbo Pascal

Tags: arrays, pascal, digits

So I have this program to do which seems pretty complicated for me. I'm having trouble understanding how subprograms exactly work and how to call them properly in orther to get what I need.
Here are the instructions of the program I need to make:
Read an X array from N positive natural numbers so that the reading ends when the number 0 is entered. (if the given numbers are `1, 2, 3, 0` then `X=(x1=1, x2=2, x3=3)` and the length of the array will be `N=3`), where `1 ≤ n ≤ 500, 1 ≤ xi ≤ 10000`. Write a program creating an Y array `[ Y=((y1,f1), (y2,f2), (y3,f3), (yk,fk))` where `y1,...,yk` are crescent numbers of the X array with the attribute that the sum of digits of the yi number are prime `[1<=i<=k].
fi [1<=i<=k]` is the number of how many times is the yi number in the X array.
Make the Y array ordered without sorting after creating the array.
You need to write the following:
a) subprogram for reading an array
b) subprogram for checking if a number is prime or not
c) subprogram that counts the sum of digits of a number
d) subprogram for inserting a number in the Y array with the given attributes
e) subprogram for creating the Y array
f) subprogram for writing an array to the screen
g) main program
Wow, I hope I was understandable. Thanks in advance to anyone who wants to help. :)

Comment: It sounds to me like what they refer to as subprograms in this exercise description is what the rest of usually refer to as procedures and functions.

Comment: Start by writing out and grouping the various tasks, and then try to further refine them step by step.

Comment: Do you understand the basic structure of a Pascal program? Has your teacher shown you how to arrange functions and subroutines within a Pascal Program? (I am asking to try to figure out where to start answering the question--but not doing your homework).

Comment: I can do it without subprograms, but the main problem is the lack of understanding I have in how procedures and functions work and how to call them properly.